# Prove there exist linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be $n$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Prove

a) if $V_1, V_2$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $\dim V_1 + \dim V_2 \ge n$ then exist such linear map $T:V \to V$ where $ker T \subset V_1$ $\ \ $ $im T \subset V_2$

b) For every linear map $T:V \to V$ exist isomorphism $T_1, T_2:V \to V$ such that $T=T_1+T_2$

I'd be grateful for any hint since I have no idea how to tackle this problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(e_1,\ldots ,e_p)$ a basis for $V_1$ and we complete it on a basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ for $V$ and let $(u_1,\ldots ,u_q)$ a basis for $V_2$ and we complete it on a basis $(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ for $V$ and notice that $p+q\ge n$. Let $1\le p'\le p$ and $1\le q'\le q$ such that $p'+q'=n$ and define $T$ by

$$T(e_i)=0,\; 1\le i\le p'$$
and

$$T(e_i)=u_{n-i+1},\; p'+1\le i\le n$$
so we see that $T$ satisfy the desired conditions.

For b) I give only a hint as you request:) Let $W$ a supplementary space to $\ker T$: $V=\ker T\oplus W$ and let $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ a  basis and adapt it to the previous decomposition. Recall that $T:W\to \operatorname{im}(T)$ is an isomorphism. Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks a lot, can you get me hint for b ? Why $T:W \to im(T)$ is an isomorphism ?

Comment: It's the first isomorphism theorem: $$T:V/\ker T\to \operatorname{im}(T)$$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I'm afraid i can't figure it out, could you help ?

Comment: So try to prove it firstly; can you prove that the restriction of $T$ to $W$ is injective? is surjective? It's easy!